# load runner response time computation

Tags: loadrunner

Assume we have a web page which loads 5 images and 2 css in separate web requests , which are triggered in parallel from the web browser

When we record this in vugen and run the load , the load runner reports the response time of the page load .

Does load runner sum up the time taken for all these web requests or it reports the elapsed time since the requests are being fired in parallel

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Good question and the answer depends on some specifics.

- Which lr protocol is being used?
- What the test script looks like between
  Lr_start_transaction(“Page_A”); and Lr_end_transaction(“Page_A”);
- Assuming web protocol is used, is the recording mode used when
  generating the test script html or URL?
- Does test script look like below?(7 resources (5 images and 2 css) in
  EXTRARES(extra resources)).

  Lr_start_transaction(“Page_A”)
  web_url("my page", 
      "URL=http://www.example.com/", 
      "Resource=0",
      "RecContentType=text/html", 
      "Referer=", 
      "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
      "Mode=HTML",
      EXTRARES, 
      "Url=/static/image1.png", ENDITEM, 
      "Url=/static/image2.png", ENDITEM, 
      "Url=/static/image3.png", ENDITEM, 
      "Url=/static/image4.png", ENDITEM, 
      "Url=/static/image5.png", ENDITEM, 
      "Url=/static/css1.css", ENDITEM, 
      "Url=/static/css2.css", ENDITEM, 
      LAST);
  Lr_end_transaction(“Page_A”)

To check whether resources being loaded in parallel, you can run a couple of  small tests.

Use a function like above and note down transaction response time.

Then run another test calling resources between web_concurrent_start/web_concurrent_end.

Then run another test calling each resource(image1, image2 .. etc) in a serial manner (not as part of EXTRARES list)

Compare the transaction response time of those three tests.

Answer (score 0):

I thought both answers are correct in LR, depending on your point of view.

In LR Analysis summary report, LR sum up the time taken for all these web requests. The response time of Transaction means,

- the start time is the first requet in this transaction
- the end time is the last request (or the response of checkpoint) in this transaction

But if you open LR Analysis Web Page Diagnostics (Open a .lrr file by LR Analysis, and choose Graphs to add Web Page Diagnostics.)
Then you could see the elapsed Download Time of each component.

[LR Analysis Web Page Diagnostics example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyq3U.png)